I don't see label filters on k8s.node.cpu.usage metrics when using kubeletstats receiver
I am using opentelemetry collector which is running as deamonset on eks cluster. I am using kubeletstats receiver to send node and pod's cpu stats to vendor backend. The data is availble on the grafana. But I am facing this issue that when i am trying to use - k8s_node_cpu_usage metrics, i can't filter it based on a label(which should be node id), in order to visualise each node cpu usages.

here is my collector configuration -
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        http:
    loki:
      protocols:
        http:
      use_incoming_timestamp: true
    kubeletstats:
      collection_interval: 20s
      auth_type: "serviceAccount"
      endpoint: "${env:K8S_NODE_IP}:10250"
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      metrics:
        k8s.node.cpu.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.memory.available:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.memory.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.cpu.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.memory.usage:
          enabled: true

thanks

Asked with project contributor - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/33791
